# AGL:"bitbake agl-demo-platform" hangs in task 16

Tags: yocto, automotive-grade-linux

I am an agl and pokey newbie, and have followed the steps in https://wiki.automotivelinux.org/agl-distro/source-code
(I am running the following in a docker container)

```
$source meta-agl/scripts/aglsetup.sh -m qemux86-64 agl-demo agl-netboot
------------ aglsetup.sh: Starting
Configuration files already exist:
   - /home/work/agl/build/conf/local.conf
   - /home/work/agl/build/conf/bblayers.conf
Skipping configuration files generation.
Use option -f|--force to overwrite existing configuration.
Generating setup manifest: /home/work/agl/build/aglsetup.manifest ... OK
Generating setup file: /home/work/agl/build/agl-init-build-env ... OK
------------ aglsetup.sh: Done
Common targets are:
  - meta-agl:          (core system)
    - agl-profile-core:
        agl-image-boot
        agl-image-minimal
        agl-image-minimal-qa

    - agl-profile-graphical:
        agl-image-weston

    - agl-profile-graphical-qt5:
        agl-image-graphical-qt5
        agl-image-graphical-qt5-crosssdk

    - agl-profile-graphical-html5
        agl-demo-platform-html5

  - meta-agl-demo:     (demo with UI)
    agl-image-ivi      (base for ivi targets)
    agl-image-ivi-qa
    agl-image-ivi-crosssdk

    agl-demo-platform  (* default demo target)
    agl-demo-platform-qa
    agl-demo-platform-crosssdk
```

```
$bitbake agl-demo-platform
```

This hangs in

```
Initialising tasks: 100% |############################################################################################| Time: 0:00:05
Sstate summary: Wanted 2729 Found 0 Missed 2729 Current 0 (0% match, 0% complete)
NOTE: Executing SetScene Tasks
NOTE: Executing RunQueue Tasks
No currently running tasks (16 of 7400)   0% ||
```

In order to debug it, I ran

```
$bitbake -DDD agl-demo-platform
...

DEBUG: Full skip list {'/home/work/agl/meta-agl/meta-netboot/recipes-core/images/initramfs-netboot-image.bb:do_packagedata', '/home/work/agl/meta-agl/meta-netboot/recipes-core/images/initramfs-netboot-image.bb:do_install', '/home/work/agl/meta-agl-demo/recipes-platform/images/agl-demo-platform.bb:do$
package', '/home/work/agl/meta-agl-demo/recipes-platform/images/agl-demo-platform.bb:do_compile', '/home/work/agl/meta-agl-demo/recipes-platform/imag
es/agl-demo-platform.bb:do_install', '/home/work/agl/meta-agl-demo/recipes-platform/images/agl-demo-platform.bb:do_packagedata', '/home/work/agl/meta
-agl-demo/recipes-platform/images/agl-demo-platform.bb:do_configure', '/home/work/agl/meta-agl/meta-netboot/recipes-core/images/initramfs-netboot-image.bb:do_configure', '/home/work/agl/meta-agl/meta-netboot/recipes-core/images/initramfs-netboot-image.bb:do_compile', '/home/work/agl/meta-agl/meta-netboot/recipes-core/images/initramfs-netboot-image.bb:do_package'}
DEBUG: Using runqueue scheduler 'speed'
DEBUG: Stampfile /home/work/agl/build/tmp/stamps/x86_64-linux/quilt-native/0.65-r0.do_fetch.e8a4c952a66942653e36f289eaf68ca5 not available
NOTE: Running task 1 of 7400 (/home/work/agl/external/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/quilt/quilt-native_0.65.bb:do_fetch)
DEBUG: Stampfile /home/work/agl/build/tmp/stamps/x86_64-linux/texinfo-dummy-native/1.0-r0.do_fetch.6af0fac94be624020d4ded1391838faa not available
NOTE: Running task 2 of 7400 (/home/work/agl/external/poky/meta/recipes-extended/texinfo-dummy-native/texinfo-dummy-native.bb:do_fetch)
DEBUG: Stampfile /home/work/agl/build/tmp/stamps/x86_64-linux/gnu-config-native/20180713+gitAUTOINC+30d53fc428-r0.do_fetch.66a4b9fc46062c0ab4c3d6bf6838$8ef not available
NOTE: Running task 3 of 7400 (virtual:native:/home/work/agl/external/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/gnu-config/gnu-config_git.bb:do_fetch)
DEBUG: Stampfile /home/work/agl/build/tmp/stamps/x86_64-linux/m4-native/1.4.18-r0.do_fetch.6762cc3ab39f2cedf73b612115bd959d not available
NOTE: Running task 4 of 7400 (/home/work/agl/external/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/m4/m4-native_1.4.18.bb:do_fetch)
DEBUG: Stampfile /home/work/agl/build/tmp/stamps/x86_64-linux/autoconf-native/2.69-r11.do_fetch.25fa26d4261bb5d4666677301aa59479 not available
NOTE: Running task 5 of 7400 (virtual:native:/home/work/agl/external/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/autoconf/autoconf_2.69.bb:do_fetch)
DEBUG: Stampfile /home/work/agl/build/tmp/stamps/x86_64-linux/automake-native/1.16.1-r0.do_fetch.0fd4964b1b460fad47bd3cfb55e06e3f not available
NOTE: Running task 6 of 7400 (virtual:native:/home/work/agl/external/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/automake/automake_1.16.1.bb:do_fetch)
DEBUG: Stampfile /home/work/agl/build/tmp/stamps/x86_64-linux/libtool-native/2.4.6-r0.do_fetch.fb99da9a9824dd7b876403694f7b783a not available
NOTE: Running task 7 of 7400 (/home/work/agl/external/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/libtool/libtool-native_2.4.6.bb:do_fetch)
DEBUG: Stampfile /home/work/agl/build/tmp/stamps/x86_64-linux/gettext-minimal-native/0.19.8.1-r0.do_fetch.d984cddf39092f50c5874c27f42c9627 not available
NOTE: Running task 8 of 7400 (/home/work/agl/external/poky/meta/recipes-core/gettext/gettext-minimal-native_0.19.8.1.bb:do_fetch)
DEBUG: Stampfile /home/work/agl/build/tmp/stamps/x86_64-linux/xz-native/5.2.4-r0.do_fetch.eb624201d02d0135b086909af9a87977 not available
NOTE: Running task 9 of 7400 (virtual:native:/home/work/agl/external/poky/meta/recipes-extended/xz/xz_5.2.4.bb:do_fetch)
DEBUG: Stampfile /home/work/agl/build/tmp/stamps/x86_64-linux/gmp-native/6.1.2-r0.do_fetch.d4d7e5eb8e67d572386a46cc21e57f8e not available
NOTE: Running task 10 of 7400 (virtual:native:/home/work/agl/external/poky/meta/recipes-support/gmp/gmp_6.1.2.bb:do_fetch)
DEBUG: Stampfile /home/work/agl/build/tmp/stamps/x86_64-linux/flex-native/2.6.0-r0.do_fetch.588daad6e54df2fe977b08ef749ef523 not available
NOTE: Running task 11 of 7400 (virtual:native:/home/work/agl/external/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/flex/flex_2.6.0.bb:do_fetch)
DEBUG: Stampfile /home/work/agl/build/tmp/stamps/x86_64-linux/zlib-native/1.2.11-r0.do_fetch.1fa21ab74fd7fedd15f87baac65b9dab not available
NOTE: Running task 12 of 7400 (virtual:native:/home/work/agl/external/poky/meta/recipes-core/zlib/zlib_1.2.11.bb:do_fetch)
DEBUG: Stampfile /home/work/agl/build/tmp/stamps/x86_64-linux/autoconf-archive-native/2018.03.13-r0.do_fetch.e880edd4650611bf6f65e254102ba230 not available

DEBUG: Stampfile /home/work/agl/build/tmp/stamps/x86_64-linux/autoconf-archive-native/2018.03.13-r0.do_fetch.e880edd4650611bf6f65e254102ba230 not available
NOTE: Running task 13 of 7400 (virtual:native:/home/work/agl/external/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/autoconf-archive/autoconf-archive_2018.03.13.bb:do_fetch)
DEBUG: Stampfile /home/work/agl/build/tmp/stamps/x86_64-linux/mpfr-native/4.0.1-r0.do_fetch.34c76de4a18ded6152d2ff68820420c9 not available
NOTE: Running task 14 of 7400 (virtual:native:/home/work/agl/external/poky/meta/recipes-support/mpfr/mpfr_4.0.1.bb:do_fetch)
DEBUG: Stampfile /home/work/agl/build/tmp/stamps/x86_64-linux/bison-native/3.0.4-r0.do_fetch.53556f21491498d19bb9e3b24cf725b2 not available
NOTE: Running task 15 of 7400 (virtual:native:/home/work/agl/external/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/bison/bison_3.0.4.bb:do_fetch)
DEBUG: Stampfile /home/work/agl/build/tmp/stamps/x86_64-linux/binutils-cross-x86_64/2.31.1-r0.do_fetch.14df04f9e0c741b374c8987222b85026 not available
NOTE: Running task 16 of 7400 (/home/work/agl/external/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/binutils/binutils-cross_2.31.bb:do_fetch)
```

When the above happens, there are the following process in `ps -ef` output

```
admin      3977   1430  0 10:48 pts/3    00:00:02 python3 /home/work/agl/external/poky/bitbake/bin/bitbake agl-demo-platform
admin      3996      1  7 10:48 ?        00:00:28 python3 /home/work/agl/external/poky/bitbake/bin/bitbake agl-demo-platform
admin      4108   3996  0 10:48 ?        00:00:00 python3 /home/work/agl/external/poky/bitbake/bin/bitbake-worker decafbad
```

It looks like there are 16(?) do_fetch tasks going on. I have tried waiting for an hour but bitbake does not move forward.

My container does not have strace enabled. Could someone please help me with debugging?

All the git repositories under agl directory except the following three are on branch icefish, not sure if it matters but just documenting it

```
external/meta-iot-cloud
* (no branch)
external/meta-python2
* (no branch)
bsp/meta-arm
* (no branch)
```

There are no `run.do_fetch` logs in $T

```
admin@623c5e680b76:/home/work/agl/build$ bitbake -e|grep ^T=
T="/home/work/agl/build/tmp/work/corei7-64-agl-linux/defaultpkgname/1.0-r0/temp"
/home/work/agl$ ls -l build/tmp/work/corei7-64-agl-linux/defaultpkgname/1.0-r0/temp/*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 admin admin   30 Jun 28 19:42 build/tmp/work/corei7-64-agl-linux/defaultpkgname/1.0-r0/temp/run.oecore_update_bblayers -> run.oecore_update_bblayers.369
-rw-r--r-- 1 admin admin 4565 Jun 28 19:42 build/tmp/work/corei7-64-agl-linux/defaultpkgname/1.0-r0/temp/run.oecore_update_bblayers.369
-rw-rw-r-- 1 admin admin 4565 Jun 28 18:02 build/tmp/work/corei7-64-agl-linux/defaultpkgname/1.0-r0/temp/run.oecore_update_bblayers.560
-rw-r--r-- 1 admin admin 4565 Jun 28 17:50 build/tmp/work/corei7-64-agl-linux/defaultpkgname/1.0-r0/temp/run.oecore_update_bblayers.715
-rw-r--r-- 1 admin admin 4565 Jun 28 17:16 build/tmp/work/corei7-64-agl-linux/defaultpkgname/1.0-r0/temp/run.oecore_update_bblayers.769
```

EDIT
There is no quilt directory in the work directory

```
$ pwd
/home/work/agl/build/tmp/work
$ find .
.
./corei7-64-agl-linux
./corei7-64-agl-linux/defaultpkgname
./corei7-64-agl-linux/defaultpkgname/1.0-r0
./corei7-64-agl-linux/defaultpkgname/1.0-r0/temp
./corei7-64-agl-linux/defaultpkgname/1.0-r0/temp/run.oecore_update_bblayers.560
./corei7-64-agl-linux/defaultpkgname/1.0-r0/temp/run.oecore_update_bblayers.633
./corei7-64-agl-linux/defaultpkgname/1.0-r0/temp/run.oecore_update_bblayers.369
./corei7-64-agl-linux/defaultpkgname/1.0-r0/temp/run.oecore_update_bblayers.715
./corei7-64-agl-linux/defaultpkgname/1.0-r0/temp/run.oecore_update_bblayers.769
./corei7-64-agl-linux/defaultpkgname/1.0-r0/temp/run.oecore_update_bblayers
```

EDIT
I could make the build start with basing my container off `crops/poky-container`.My container did not have the following

1. new user `usersetup` and `sudoers.usersetup`
2. execution of `/usr/bin/distro-entry.sh` which in turn runs `/opt/poky/3.1/environment-setup-x86_64-pokysdk-linux`

Comment: The logs would be in the corresponding recipes working directories, look e.g. under build/tmp/work/corei7-64-agl-linux/quilt/

Comment: @JussiKukkonen No such directory, I only have `defaultpkgname` inside `corei7-64-agl-linux` and not `quilt` or `gnu-config-native`
Also, the task no 16(`poky/meta/recipes-devtools/binutils/binutils-cross_2.31.bb`) requires 
`binutils.inc`, `binutils-${PV}.inc` and `binutils-cross.inc`

But the only `do_fetch` in `recipes-devtools` is in `external/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/gcc/gcc-shared-source.inc`
`do_fetch[noexec] = "1"`
Is this a problem due to noexec? I haven't made any changes in the sources though

Comment: fetch is usually not implemented by the recipes directly (because all fetches essentially do the same thing): this is unlikely to be a problem in the recipes as they work for everyone else. Have you tested that you can access the internet from the container manually? Do you need to setup proxies to do that?

Comment: @JussiKukkonen wget from inside the container works 

` $ cd /tmp`

`$ wget cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v4.x/linux-4.17.2.tar.xz --2020-06-29 07:09:25-- cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v4.x/linux-4.17.2.tar.xz ...Saving to: linux-4.17.2.tar.xz linux-4.17.2.tar.xz 100%97.43M 23.8MB/s in 4.1s 2020-06-29 07:09:32 (23.5 MB/s) - linux-4.17.2.tar.xz saved [102167060/102167060] `
...........
`$ ls -l linux-4.17.2.tar.xz -rw-r--r-- 1 admin admin 102167060 Jun 16 2018 linux-4.17.2.tar.xz `

Comment: oh sorry, I think I used the wrong machine name in the path: quilt that's being fetched is for a native build so maybe look for logs under `build/tmp/work/<build-host-arch>/...`

Comment: @JussiKukkonen there is no directory other than `defaultpkgname` inside `build/tmp/work/corei7-64-agl-linux`